# Get token with OpenID in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, openid

I would like to know if there is a way to obtain an access token through OpenID in Flutter (Dart). I can do it through Postman and I can also use a WebView in Flutter, however, I would like the app (Android) to be able to open the browser to do the whole process until you get the desired token...just like in Postman.

With Postman, I do it this way:

1- Request [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vceA1.png)

2 - Result [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVioA.png)

I have tried to use the "openid_client" plugin with the following code, but I am not successful. It gives me one error :

> E/flutter ( 6080): Tried calling: contains("openid")

```
      authenticate(Uri uri, String clientId, List<String> scopes) async {
    // create the client
    var issuer = await Issuer.discover(uri);
    var client = new Client(issuer, clientId);
    // create a function to open a browser with an url
    urlLauncher(String url) async {
      //String url2 = issuer.metadata['data'].values.first.toString();
      if (await canLaunch(url)) {
        await launch(url, forceWebView: true);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $url';
      }
    }

    // create an authenticator
    var authenticator = new Authenticator(client, scopes: scopes, urlLancher: urlLauncher);
    // starts the authentication
    var c = await authenticator.authorize();
    // close the webview when finished
    closeWebView();
    // return the user info
    return await c.getUserInfo();
  }
```

(...)

```
  RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () => authenticate(
        Uri.parse('https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/auth/login/?application_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&nofollow=1'),
        null,
        ['Access Token', 'account_id', 'expires_at', 'nickname']),
    child: Text('OpenID', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
  )
```

Can some brilliant mind help me? Am I in the right direction or should I move to other solution?

Answer (score 0):

The **openid** scope is a required scope that always must be included. So try to add it to the list of scopes that you ask the token service for.

In your picture the **scope** parameter in the first request seems to be empty.

The scope parameter represents what you want to have access to and what information you want to know from the user. Attached is a picture from one of my training classes describing the scopes on a high level:

[image]

The openid scope is required and often you also see requests for scopes like email and profile.

Comment: Hello Tore. "In your picture the scope parameter in the first request seems to be empty." - yes, but it works like a charm on Postman...I realy want to have some code similar to it on Flutter. By the way...what is "scope" for? Can you give me some kind of explanation on it? Can you tell me by the pictures what can that potentialy be? Thank you.

Comment: I understand your answer on the "scope" question, so, my guess is that my scope is "access_token", according to the information on my second image. Owever I still have no solution for my problem.

Comment: ...my bad! My scope is "OpenID" and not "access_token"...

Comment: Im still facing my problem: I have tried to use the "openid_client" plugin with the following code, but I am not successful. It gives me one error :

E/flutter ( 6080): Tried calling: contains("openid")

Comment: what scopes are you asking the server for?

Comment: Im asking for OpenID only.

Comment: try to ask for openid lowercase?

Comment: Still the same error. I understand that you already notice that in PostMan everything is OK....I need the solution for Flutter!

Comment: I would use fiddler to intercept the failing request and post the request and response that is failing in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your support, but my guess is that is not the way. I just want to use openid_client to get a result the same way as I do it in Postman. If by chance anybody can help...

Comment: No problems! If it works in postman, but not in in your client, why not just use a tool like Fiddler, and compare the requests from postman and your client and figure out what parameter is missing? or not the same?  Perhaps time to create a new question with some update on your progress? it would be useful to see the complete request made from your client.

Comment: OK, So, I´ve decided to use a new library (FlutterWebAuth) because, al least I have some results, no just one error...For historic purposes, I will answer my own question and I wont edit my previous original question, because it remais the same "how to"...

Comment: Sounds fine to me!

Answer (score 0):

Moved to FlutterWebAuth with this code:

```
  void authenticateWebAuth() async {
    // Present the dialog to the user
    final result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(
      url: "https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/auth/login/?application_id=XXXe272eXXXac833eXXXf093d032c7fe&display=popup",
      callbackUrlScheme: "",
    );

// Extract token from resulting url
    final token = Uri.parse(result).queryParameters['access_token'];
    print('access_token');
    print(token);
  }
```

The problem is that it wont passes the first statement (FlutterWebAuth.authenticate). Knowing that the access_token is in the URL...how to make this work?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki2e9.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You would use the getTokenResponse() followed by tokenresponse.accessToken

```
var authenticator = new Authenticator(client, scopes: scopes, urlLancher: urlLauncher);
var c = await authenticator.authorize();

tokenResponse = await c.getTokenResponse();
var token = tokenResponse.accessToken;
```